# Can't change POST request to GET request using Gin/GoLang

Tags: go

I seem to not be able to change POST method with GET method in Gin Framework. When I receive a request, I want to check credentials of it and, if valid, redirect to another page, which has a GET endpoint. Whenever I use `c.Request.Method="GET"` it seems to change request only for the current endpoint, but redirected one still has the original method, i.e. POST method.

Code:

```
auth.GET("/sign-in", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.File("../../html/index.html")
})

auth.POST("/sign-in", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Request.Method = "GET"
    c.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, "/profile/:pid")
})
```

[image: Request Logs]

`Code 307` request is originally `POST` request, changed to `GET` by the endpoint itself.

Doing `c.Request.Method="GET"` didn't help. Couldn't find answer either. Any idea how to change this behavior? Is creating a new request the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

307 status code [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307) says:

> The method and the body of the original request are reused to perform the redirected request. In the cases where you want the method used to be changed to GET, use 303 See Other instead.

So if you change `http.StatusTemporaryRedirect` to `http.StatusSeeOther`, it will work without changing the original request method.

Comment: Worked, thanks! Will put that up in the question as answer, marked too.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that setting `c.Request.Method = "GET"` in the `POST` endpoint will only change the method for that endpoint, and the method of the request being sent in the redirect will still be `POST`.

The correct way to achieve the desired behavior is to use the `c.Request.Method` to set the method but instead of using `Redirect` which is specific to the current request you should redirect with `c.HTML` which makes a new request and renders the new endpoint you want to visit using the correct method you set.

The `http.StatusSeeOther` status code you are mentioning is also the correct one to use in this case, as it indicates that the resource has been temporarily moved, and the client should use the new URI provided in the Location header field to access the resource.

So your code could look like this:

```
auth.POST("/sign-in", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Request.Method = "GET"
    c.HTML(http.StatusSeeOther, "profile/:pid", nil)
})
```

This way you are redirecting to the new location but with a new request, with the method you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Go reads the endpoints procedurally, so if it hits a GET -request, it will not search for another GET -request for the same endpoint. The most "highest" one wins. AFAIK, I might be wrong here. But ...

What if you change the logic to something like following?

```html
auth.POST("/sign-in", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Request.Method = "GET"

    // Serve the index -page

    // Implement the credential check logic here

    // Perform validation

    ...

    isValidUser, _ := checkCredentials(user.Username, user.Password)

    if isValidUser {
      c.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, "/profile/:pid")    
    }

    ...
})
```

With this logic and continue from here - while dropping the first GET -request altogether.

Note: This is not valid code, just ideas how you could proceed.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What exactly is your goal by putting c.Request.Method up first? Like, giving it time to execute before redirecting? If so, I tried `sleep` to 'pause' the execution between setting and redirecting but didn't work. If it's something else, please let me know

Comment: It's also hitting the redirection, without a problem but one - method after redirection is POST instead of GET. I don't have GET endpoint for `/profile/:pid` and it results in 404